# PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and PL/SQL: ORA-00925: missing or invalid option

Tags: oracle

I got this error while creating a trigger to multiply 2 columns i.e. total=price*quantity in SQL server

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROD_TOTAL
AFTER INSERT ON Products
BEGIN
set Total = ProdPrice * ProdQuantity;
END;
/
```

Output :
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors trigger PROD_TOTAL
Errors TRIGGER PROD_TOTAL:

### LINE/COL ERROR

2/2      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/6      PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

This is my code, I am not able to understand the problem in this code.
Please help me in solving this error.

Comment: can you include the DDL for the `Products` table?

Comment: PL/SQL is oracle, not sql server. You will struggle if you try to use the wrong SQL dialect with your database engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CREATE TRIGGER statement itself is incorrect, it should be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROD_TOTAL
ON Products
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SQL STATEMENT
END;
```

Furthermore, your SET is not a valid SQL statement.

If Total is intended to be a variable, you are not declaring it anywhere.

If Total is intended to be a column from Products, you are not referencing Products in the statement, so it doesn't know what Total, ProdPrice, or ProdQuantity are.

My guess is that you are probably looking to update the Products table after a record is inserted to set the column Total equal to ProdPrice by ProdQuantity, which I assume are also columns from the Products table.

If that's the case, here is a db fiddle that accomplishes that:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b71a27c8b412048a8b8a88468804650c

Answer (score 0):

Though you mentioned SQL server in your question your mentioned error is from Oracle. So I am considering that you are trying to create the trigger in oracle server.
As I understood you have a table named **Products** consisting colums Total, ProductPrice and ProductQuantity. You want to use trigger to calculate value of Total column while inserting data into the table in price and quantity fields

You can use below code to do so:

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER PROD_TOTAL 
before INSERT ON Product 
for each row 
BEGIN 
:new.total := :new.price * :new.quantity; 
END;
```

You can also use calculated field instead of trigger to get the same result.
Please let me know if you are looking for the solution in sql server platform.

Comment: I am still getting the error in fact this time I got  3 different errors:   
2/1      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TOTAL'
2/15     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PRICE'
2/28     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.QUANTITY'

Comment: Sorry i misspelled your variable name.

Comment: @Sushmitashukla Try below code:
CREATE or replace TRIGGER PROD_TOTAL 
before INSERT ON Products 
for each row 
BEGIN 
:new.total := :new.ProdPrice   * :new.ProdQuantity; 
END;